# How do I disable psycopg2 connection pooling?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have configured pgpool-II for postgres connection pooling and I want to disable psycopg2 connection pooling. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`psycopg2` doesn't pool connections unless you explicitely use the `psycopg.pool` module.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can. Dan McKinley bemoaned this fact (among some other interesting issues) in his blog post [Python PostgreSQL Driver Authors Hate You](http://mcfunley.com/445/python-postgresql-driver-authors-hate-you).